# How to manage authentication across handler classes in google app engine /w python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication

Taking into account that I barely know python and am simply following the "hello-world" example here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/

I'm unclear as to how I would: use a "MainHandler" class mapped to '/' as a welcome page, ask the user to login and then only allow logged-in users to access a "EditorHandler" class mapped to '/editor'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked a very broad question, and provided no details about what (if any) framework you're planning to use to implement your app.  I guess you are probably using [webapp](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/)?

The basic idea would be to [create a login url](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions.html) that you redirect the user to, or you provide to them.  If you want them redirected to an edit page on your app, you can specify a dest_url when calling `create_login_url`:

```
users.create_login_url(dest_url='/edit')
```

Within your code you can secure your edit handler easily in [app.yaml](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status) or with the ['@login_required'](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/utilmodule.html) decorator, depending on how you've setup your app.

Comment: Well, the example I was referring to uses the webapp framework, so I though it was implied in my question. Nevertheless the @login_required decorator did the trick and moved me on to the next problem: Do I have to stick that in front of *EVERY* method that requires login?

Comment: @quickredfox, no you could also use app.yaml to require login for some urls, see 'login: required' in the 'configuring your app' docs (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status).  If you split your code into two files it will probably make it easier to see how that would work.

Comment: Yeah, saw that, thanks a lot for the info. Though I plan on NOT using the google connect mechanisms so that leaves me with having to implement a lot of stuff by hand... hence the reason for my original confusion. Had I done it the GAE way, I'd probably be a lot further now, but would be dependent on GFC.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work: http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/login-decorator

Although I dont understand the magic behind most of it, it's probably due to my lack of python skills.

Some comments on that article also point to more "native" solutions:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/utilmodule.html